# Unable to run Windows 8 in full screen mode in VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8

Not quite sure if this is on topic or not but all of the googling I could find referred to changes to make to get Windows 8 to run in full screen mode on Windows, however I haven't found any documents or guides on running Windows 8 in full screen mode for Ubuntu.

I am running the 64-bit version of Windows 8 on virtualbox 4.2 and I do have the guest additions installed

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to install the virtualbox expansion pack:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.4/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.4-81684.vbox-extpack

Also, I would make sure hardware virtualization is enabled:

SETTINGS > SYSTEM > ACCELERATION TAB > both checkboxes checked

Comment: Thanks, tested this and it worked correctly.  Marked the answer as the soluton

Comment: I tried this and got this error: Failed to install the Extension Pack /home/juliofdiaz/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.4-81684.vbox-extpack.

VBoxExtPackRegister returned VERR_VERSION_MISMATCH, pReg=0000000000000000 ErrInfo='VirtualBox version mismatch - expected 4.2 got 4.1'.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ExtPackManager
Interface: IExtPackManager {3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554}

Comment: @JulioDiaz Make sure that your version of virtualbox is up-to-date; currently version 4.2.6:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: @JulioDiaz Make sure that you are using the latest version of the extenison pack - which is here:http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.6/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.6-82870.vbox-extpack

Answer (score 0):

Install Guest Addition in safe mode, it is a lot more complicated then needs to be to get to safe mode. follow instruction at how to geek.

http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/

after reboot I did go full screen (host + f), scale mode (host+c) full screen, both work as expected... seamless mode (host + l) while works, it does not work correctly, unable to access win 8 on screen features